# Review Queues and the PMSE Notice Board

Tags: discussion, announcement

I went through the close vote review queue and cleaned up some stuff that had been lingering around for awhile that should have probably been put on hold a little sooner.

Most of the posts had 3 or 4 close votes already, so it's great to see more people involved in community moderation and keeping things looking good!

Here is [the list of closed posts from my review history](https://pm.stackexchange.com/review/close/history).  If there's anything you think can be edited and improved, cleaned up, and reopened, please feel free to seek clarification from the author, make an edit, cast a reopen vote, or start a meta discussion to get others involved who may be able to help.

Also, a great way to get attention for posts that need edits, close votes, etc is to drop a link in the [PMSE Notice board](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/380/the-pmse-notice-board) where others will see it.

Again, it's great to see more people contributing to community moderation. If we use the communication tools on this platform to our advantage, perhaps we can get more people involved!